# Hibernate Native Query: java.sql.SQLException: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, thymeleaf

I will really appreciate if you can check it. I am trying to make optional a query parameter but having a problem with operand count since it is a list.

Here is my code:

```
public static final String FETCH_FILTERING = "select * from arbor.product where 1=1 ";
    public static final String FETCH_FILTERING_COLOR = "and ((:colors) is null or color in (:colors)) ";
    public static final String FETCH_FILTERING_GENDER = "and ((:genders) is null or gender in (:genders)) ";
    @Query(value = FETCH_FILTERING+FETCH_FILTERING_COLOR+FETCH_FILTERING_GENDER, nativeQuery = true)
    List<Product> findByColorsAndGenders(@Param("colors")List<String> colors, @Param("genders")List<String> genders);
```

Here is the error:

```
019-12-17 11:03:53.104  WARN 1204 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1241, SQLState: 21000
2019-12-17 11:03:53.104 ERROR 1204 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Operand should contain 1 column(s)
2019-12-17 11:03:53.140 ERROR 1204 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you found any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using COALESCE.

Here is the solution....

```
public static final String FETCH_FILTERING_COLOR = "and (COALESCE(:colors) is null or color in (:colors)) ";
```

COALESCE returns the first non-null element from the given list and returns null if list if null.

Details-
https://www.hellojava.com/a/50005.html

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra `Parentheses` from `IN`

Please make sure your parameter doesn't have any extra Parentheses.

**Note:**

`SELECT '1' IN ('2','1','3');  Result: 1(TRUE)` [**See demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/68640/1)

`SELECT '1' IN (('2','1','3')); Result: [Err] 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)` [**See demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/68638)

Answer (score 0):

"and ((:colors) is null " this is wrong expression mysql knows nothing about :colors 
it should be

```
public static final String FETCH_FILTERING = "select * from arbor.product where 1=1 ";
    public static final String FETCH_FILTERING_COLOR = "and (color is null or color in (:colors)) ";
    public static final String FETCH_FILTERING_GENDER = "and (gender is null or gender in (:genders)) ";
    @Query(value = FETCH_FILTERING+FETCH_FILTERING_COLOR+FETCH_FILTERING_GENDER, nativeQuery = true)
    List<Product> findByColorsAndGenders(@Param("colors")List<String> colors, @Param("genders")List<String> genders);
```

Comment: Hello Ahmed, I need to replace null with 0 if the list is empty. Otherwise query returns nothing.

Comment: btw COALESCE is NOT working since it is a list.

select * from arbor.product where color in (COALESCE(:colors,0)) and gender in (COALESCE(:genders,0))"

Comment: don't get what you mean , if you mean replace :colors parameter , then you should handle this before you call the method